# Error al realizar Mock a un método estático en JAVA (pruebas unitarias)

Tags: java, junit, pruebas-unitarias, mockito, junit-4

Estoy realizando la prueba unitariade una implementación de una clase en Java con **Junit4** y **Mockito** en la versión *2.20.0*.

La clase que se está realizando la prueba unitaria es **GeneralImpl** con el método **consultar**, ***GetRest* no se instancia**:

```
@Component
public class GeneralImpl implements GeneralService {
  Respuesta consultar(String url)  {
    String res = GetRest.get(url);
    Respuesta response = new Respuesta();
    response.setData(res);
      return response;
  }
}
```

La clase es GetRest contiene el método estático generico **get** recibe el parámetro de *String url*.

```
@Component("getRest")
public class GetRest {
public static String get(String url){
         String response;
  InputStream is = null;
  try {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.connect();
    is = con.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
    response = "";
    String aux;
    while ((aux = br.readLine()) != null) {
      response += aux;
    }
    br.close();
    ir.close();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    response = null;
  } 
  finally {
    is.close();
  }
  return response;
}
}
```

hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GeneralImplTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private GeneralImpl general;

  @Mock // tarte tambien con Spy
  private GetRest getRest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void generalTest() throws Exception {
    when(getRest.get(anyString())).thenReturn("respuesta simulada");
    Respuesta respuesta = general.consultar("aqui la url del consumo");
    assertNotNull(respuesta);
  }
}
```

El error que tengo es que en la parte del **when**, no me realiza la simulación del llamado del método **get**, es como si no existiera y realiza el proceso normal (tratando de conectarse a la URL).

Comment: Mockito 2.2.0 no soporta la prueba unitaria de métodos estáticos por si solo, esto es posible después de la versión 3.4.0; 

Busca acerca de PowerMockito parece q previo a 3.4 te ayuda a poder probar métodos estáticos.